# highlighting search results in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, highlighting

how do i highlight search results from mysql query using php?

this is my **[modified]** code:

```
$search_result = "";

$search_result = $_GET["q"];

$result = mysql_query('SELECT cQuotes, vAuthor, cArabic, vReference FROM thquotes WHERE cQuotes LIKE "%' . $search_result .'%" ORDER BY idQuotes DESC', $conn)
  or die ('Error: '.mysql_error());


function h($s) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($s, ENT_QUOTES);
} 


?>

    <div class="caption">Search Results</div>
<div class="center_div">
<table>
    <?php while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <?php $cQuotes = preg_replace($search_result, "<div class='highlight'>".$search_result."</div>", $row['cQuotes']); ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right; font-size:15px;"><?php h($row['cArabic']) ?></td>
            <td style="font-size:16px;"><?php h($cQuotes) ?></td>
            <td style="font-size:12px;"><?php h($row['vAuthor']) ?></td>
            <td style="font-size:12px; font-style:italic; text-align:right;"><?php h($row['vReference']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use preg_replace();, when it finds a match in your text you could place a div with a class of highlight around the matching word. You would then add a background color and border to the highlight class to make it stand out

preg_replace expect 3 parameters;

1. the first one is what you are looking for
2. second one is what should it be changed to
3. The string of text he should search and replace from

so for example

```
<div class="center_div">
    <table>
    <caption>Search Results</caption>
    <?php while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<?php $arabic = preg_replace("/".$search_result."/", "<div class='highlight'>".$search_result."</div>", h($row['cArabic'])); ?>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right; font-size:15px;"><?php $arabic ?></td>
                <td style="font-size:16px;"><?php h($row['cQuotes']) ?></td>
                <td style="font-size:12px;"><?php h($row['vAuthor']) ?></td>
                <td style="font-size:12px; font-style:italic; text-align:right;"><?php h($row['vReference']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
    </div>
```

I only did it for arabic but you might need to do that for cQuotes, vAuthor and vReference as well.

Comment: thanks. i did that, but for quotes. `<?php $cQuotes = preg_replace($search_result, "<div class='highlight'>".$search_result."</div>", $row['cQuotes']); ?>
        <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right; font-size:15px;"><?php h($row['cArabic']) ?></td>
   <td style="font-size:16px;"><?php h($cQuotes) ?></td>` . .however, this is not showing the Quotes records at all [it's displaying arabic, reference and author].

Comment: do you mean that it's not dipslaying the right content where it should? that's weird. Can you change the code in your question to show what you currently have? this will be easier to see what's not right

Comment: it's not displaying anything from the cQuotes record. modified the code.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer above, you need to add / before and after the first parameter of the preg_replace function. I saw that when I tested the code and I received that error, I guess you have error reporting turned off or something hiding it.

Comment: after a few more modification, it displays the record now, but still doesn't highlight the searched keyword.. `<?php $cQuotes = preg_replace('/$search_result/'  , '/<span class="highlight">$search_result<\/span>/', $row['cQuotes']); ?>`

Comment: did you style the class highlight in your css file?

Comment: yes, i did. `.highlight {
background-color: #FFE066;
font-weight:bold;
}`

Comment: I added an inline style and it worked, are you sure you have linked correctly to your stylesheet? user firebug to see if the div was added to the matched word and use the web developer addon for firefox to check if it can find the style

Comment: checked thru firebug. the div doesn't add to the matched word although the style is there in the css. not sure what is wrong? could it be that the css of other elements in the page conflict with the css of this one?

Comment: no, if the div is not added it has nothing to do with the styles. maybe it's because of your function htmlspecialchars() it might alter html tags and therefore remove or alter the div with the class.
maybe run the function before replacing, see the code in my answer above, I updated it again

Comment: doesn't work. plus the Quotes field records display out of div.

Comment: I checked back your code in the comments, preg_replace('/$search_result/' , '/<span class="highlight">$search_result<\/span>/', $row['cQuotes']); ?> <- don't add single quotes, variables won't work between single quotes, use double quotes or concatenate like I did in the code I provided above.

Comment: did that. .nothing. i'm assuming there's nothing wrong with the code itself, but there must be some conflict with other elements. .

Comment: i executed the code independently on a test page. it works. but i cannot understand why it isnt working on this page..

Comment: Send me a link or send me a piece of the code and I can check it out for you (my email is idealvisions@live.com)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using a JavaScript library called [HiLite](http://scott.yang.id.au/code/se-hilite/).  It works pretty well.

Comment: thanks for this, but i'd like to do it in php. any help appreciated.