# How to preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace something like http://www.somesite.com/videos/video23.mp4 with something like `<some_my_tag>http://www.somesite.com/videos/video23.mp4</some_my_tag>`. How to do it in PHP?

Comment: Your "something like" is a little vague. What can change in that URL?

Comment: I think it is a perfectly valid question

Answer (score 3):

As you said that "Everything except .mp4" can change in the URL, then you can use this:

```
$NewStr = preg_replace('#http://(.+?)\.mp4#i', '<some_my_tag>http://$1.mp4</some_my_tag>', $Str);
```

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/videos/video23.mp4";
$output = preg_replace('/((?:http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9\/\?=_#&%~-]+(\.[a-z0-9\/\?=_#&%~-]+)+)|(www(\.[a-z0-9\/\?=_#&%~-]+){2,})/', '<some_my_tag>$1</some_my_tag>', $url);
```

The regex pattern will allow you to find any kind of url's

I answered a (more or less) similar questions here -> [highlighting search results in php/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738555/highlighting-search-results-in-php-mysql/2739238#2739238)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('#http://(.+?)\.mp4#i', '<tab>http://$1.mp4</tag>', $text)
```

Comment: exactly, but you then asume there are only links ending with .mp4